# How to get mysql automatically running when I start tomcat apache on Windows?

Tags: mysql, windows, web-server

When starting my Tomcat Apache Server, I've been having to start up mysql before than using the `mysqld` command. I was wondering if there was a work around this so that I could have mysql start up when I run the startup.bat command for tomcat.

Sorry, if this is an easy question. I have a very limited understanding of both databases and web servers so I wasn't able to find or understand any information I found on google.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to love this.

Just install mysqld as a Windows Service. Ready ?

From the Windows DOS shell (ran as Administrator), go to the folder where mysqld.exe is located

Run this

```
mysqld --install
```

That's it. You can go to

- ControlPanel
- Administrative Tools
- Service

When the Services Window opens, scroll alphabetically can you will see MySQL as a service

Restart Windows

When Windows comes back up, mysqld.exe should already be running.

Give it a Try !!!

See my other from ServerFault : (`Feb 10, 2011` : [Installing isolated instance of MySQL on Windows using silent install with .msi](https://serverfault.com/a/234125/69271))